# How to get the is_eligible_promo status of a player? New Payer Promotions is not working now

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-credits

Now, in the Facebook [document of user info](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user), it appears is_eligible_promo is only visible for the apps, of which the user is the administrator. But according to the [Payer Promotions document](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/payments/payer_promotion/), the app need to get the is_eligible_promo status before prompt the Payer Promotions Dialog. Now after the API change, how do we detect whether a player is eligible for payer promotion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as stated in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/payerpromotions/ you can get it by sending get request to:
https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID?fields=is_eligible_promo&access_token=USER_ACCESS_TOKEN
you'll have is_eligible_promo field in response json IF the user is eligible, if not, you'll only get user id.